# how to converted the excel file into sql file

Tags: php, sql, excel

hi i want to converted my excel file into sql file can any one know what should i do for converting? i dont know how to converted.

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by convert? What do you need in SQL?

Comment: As above? Do you want to generate Insert statements / link to a live database and push the data out? A sample of your data would be handy too, along with which RDBMS you are using. And you target data model.

Comment: Easy way: Excel file => upload all data in DB table => dump the DB table => .sql file

Comment: Read the Excel file; loop through each row; insert cells from that row into SQL.... more details of your xls and database needed if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: i have a ms-excel file i want to change it to sql @antypaton @oded

Comment: @lavan - xls or xlsx? what is the structure of your Excel data in the worksheets? What database are you using? What is the structure of your database tables?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Usually when I deal with Excel spreadsheets, I have users export as .csv
If this is an option, I would start by looking at the fgetcsv function here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 2):

Use sql convertor from below link

http://www.sqlconverter.com/

OR

You need to convert the .xls  file to .csv(comma seperated file) and then use the loader to load the data if you want to load the .xls data to database.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com) products.
I used Navicat for MySQL for example and it provides great flexibility in Importing Excel sheets in Mysql tables.
From there you can run any type of SQL query

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://etlint.com) is web application tool that allows fast Excel to MySQL conversion. 
Excel data does not have a Schema by default and this tool allows you to define it interactively with the help of a wizard.

**Input**

An Excel (xls / xlsx) data file, whose format is given in the documentation they provide.

**Output**

A .sql export file (which can be imported into a MySQL database) is available for download after the conversion is done. (And it works pretty fast)

The other option is to export to CSV first. Excel can export to CSV and then MySQL can import CSV via LOAD command or PHPMyAdmin. The schema should be defined before. Its a little longer process.